# Can Local UIWebViews Access Web?

Tags: php, iphone, objective-c, ios, uiwebview

I've got some embedded (read: local) html files with forms loaded in a UIWebView in my app. The form action attempts to call a script I've got on a server. I know the script is working because it has been tested on a local machine and inputs values into the database as needed.

However, when I have the local form on the app attempt to do this, the url for the script is called (and even the webViewDidLoad delegate method is called) BUT, values are NOT inserted into the database. Is it possible for local html files to submit to scripts on the web? Or are they limited to the local filesystem because they are present there?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have described is possible.
Are you sure you are returning YES when shouldStartLoadWithRequest: is called?

Comment: This was the issue. I was returning true, changed it to YES and it worked. Very strange it didn't work when returning true...

Answer (score 0):

I don't see why the UIWebView couldn't submit a form to the web, but obviously the script would have to not be a relative path.

So you could do

```
<form id="frm1" action="http://somewebsite.com/formsubmit.php">
```

instead of the usual

```
<form id="frm1" action="/formsubmit.php">
```

and of course would need to make sure you have an internet connection.

Hope that helps, if not, feel free to clarify.

Comment: Ya I've used the full path already, made that mistake the first time heh. I've even printed the url in the webViewDidStartLoad delegate method and it is correct, it is pointing to my script. Because I am able to submit blank values on this form, I've visited the url on a browser and it submits blanks to the DB, but through the app it doesn't! So I'm not sure if my issue is that this is a local file and thus cannot submit to a server outside the filesystem

Comment: Are there any other dependencies that this page with the form, may have that might need to be bundled into the app?

Comment: The script could be a relative path.